# Eigenvalues of product of symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory

Let $T_1, \ldots, T_n$ by real symmetric positive definite matrices, with eigenvalues bounded below by $\mu > 0$.
Can I say
$$
\frac{x^T T_1 T_2 \ldots T_n x}{x^T x} \geq \mu^n
$$
If these matrices commute the result is straightforward, but I'm interested in the case where these matrices don't necessarily commute.

**Edit**: Not sure that you can say this for the $n=2$ case either.

Comment: Knowing the eigenvalues have a lower bound like that is not sufficient for what you want, because $x^T M x$ is unrelated to the eigenvalues of $M$ for $M$ not symmetric. In particular, can't the left side be negative already for $n=2$?

Comment: Oh good point. I'm not sure. In the $n=2$ case the eigenvalues are real and positive and so I thought that implied $x^T T_1 T_2 x > 0$, but I guess that may not be true.

Comment: Yes indeed, perhaps you can find a vector $x$ making the left-hand side negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the product $M=T_1T_2$ of two positive definite symmetric matrices has real and positive eigenvalues. And conversely, every matrix $M$ with real positive eigenvalues can be factored $M=T_1T_2$ as above. But $x^TMx$ does not need to be positive. Here is an example:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & a \\ -a & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad \sqrt3<a<2.$$
The eigenvalues, roots of $X^2-2X-3+a^2$, are real and positive, while
$x^TMx=3x_1^2-x_2^2$ is indefinite.